# C++ primer 5 ed. StrBlobPtr de-crement operator

Tags: c++

Is this a typo?

In C++ primer 5 th. ed page 702:

```
StrBlobPtr& StrBlobPtr::operator--()
{
    // if curr is zero, decrementing it will yield an invalid subscript
    --curr;       // move the current state back one element
    check(-1, "decrement past begin of StrBlobPtr");
    return *this;
}
```

So as you can see passing `-1` to check will causes it always throw. Does he mean `check(curr, "decrement past begin of StrBlobPtr");`?

And here is a snippet of how `check` is implemented:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>
StrBlobPtr::check(size_type pos, const std::string &msg) const {
  auto ret = wptr.lock();
  if (!ret)
    throw std::runtime_error("unbound StrBlobPtr");
  if (pos >= ret->size())
    throw std::out_of_range(msg);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: @tachi Uchiwa If curr means position then indeed it seems there should be check( curr, "decrement past begin of StrBlobPtr");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked my C++ Primer 6th ed., and the following code appears on page 567:

> ```
> StrBlobPtr& StrBlobPtr::operator--()
> {
>     // if curr is zero, decrementing it will yield an invalid subscript
>     --curr;       // move the current state back one element
>     check(curr, "decrement past begin of StrBlobPtr");
>     return *this;
> }
> ```

The implementation of `StrBlobPtr` has apparently changed a lot, but this should be enough to confirm that `-1` is a typo and has been fixed in the 6th edition.

---

In fact, this is mentioned on the [C++ Primer Errata](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html):

> - Page 567: In the `StrBlobPtr::operator--()` function, the call to check should pass `curr` as the first argument, not `-1`.